# Enable Javascript for local files in VBA WebBrowser Control

Tags: vba, browser

I find it rather perplexing that IE7 enables Javascript by default on the Internet zone, but disables it for local HTML files [My Computer zone] (the internet is now more secure than your local computer?), but anyway...

I have an application in VBA using the WebBrowser  control to open a local HTML file (say, file:///C:\somefile.html) which has Javascript in it.  I'd like for this Javascript to be executed.  Is there any way (from VBA code) to force the browser to allow this Javascript? (taking into consideration that it's disabled by default)

It would be ideal if I wouldn't have to rely on registry editing of any sorts, or tell the user of the application to change their Internet Explorer settings.
I've also tried setting up a localhost webserver and serving the file from there.  Obviously works perfectly since IE considers this to be the Internet zone, but I'd like it if I didn't have to try coding a webserver from VBA either.

System is Windows XP with IE7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, probably not a "true" solution, but is enough for my needs.
One can use the `WebBrowser.Document.parentWindow.execScript` function to inject Javascript into the page.
I guess it may be possible to implement something similar to [Prototype's evalScripts function](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalScripts) here so that it effectively evaluates any scripts on the page.  One may need to double-check that the scripts haven't already been allowed by potentially different security settings.
I don't know how it affects linked script files.

(for my own application, I control the HTML file so I just extract all the Javascript into a separate file and execute it using the above method).